# Select multiple rows

Tags: java, php, html, mysql, row

I want take all member of a field if their id is equal to 1.

**Database:**

[image: db screenshot]

The problem is that when I try to take all photodirectory I get only the first photodirectory and the other 2 no.

**Error:**

[image: error screenshot]

**Code:**

```html
<?php

$yui1 = "SELECT photodirectory FROM photos WHERE photoowner='" . $userid . "'";
$rquery1 = mysqli_query($connDirectory, $yui1);
echo "rquery1 is equal to: "; 
var_dump($rquery1);
echo "</br>";

if($fotoutente = mysqli_fetch_row($rquery1)){ //fotoutente = userphoto

 for($c = 0; $c < count($fotoutente); $c++){
  echo '<img src="../' . $fotoutente["{$c}"] . '">' . "</br>";

    }
 
 echo "fotoutente is equal to: ";
 var_dump($fotoutente);
 
}
?>
```

How can i take all member of photodirectory if their id is 1?
Anyway the php code above is for create an array with all directory of photodirectory if etc etc etc etc...

Please save me and lord Gaben to defeat playmysql4.
Sorry for bad English but I'm Italian...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redo your code properly by iterating with a `while` loop and using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` through your results.

Do it this way:

```
<?php

$yui1 = "SELECT photodirectory FROM photos WHERE photoowner= $userid ";
$result = mysqli_query($connDirectory, $yui1);
echo "rquery1 is equal to: ";
var_dump($result);
echo "</br>";

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<img src="../' . $row["photodirectory"] . '">' . "</br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Against SQL injection:

```
<?php
if (ctype_digit(strval($userid)) === false) {
    echo "UserID is not valid!";
    exit();
}
$userid_secure = bin2hex($userid);
$rquery1 = mysqli_query($connDirectory, "SELECT photodirectory FROM photos WHERE photoowner=UNHEX('$userid_secure')";

if (mysqli_num_rows($rquery1) > 0) {
    while ($fotoutente = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rquery1)) {
        echo '<img src="../'.$fotoutente["photodirectory"].'"></br>';
    }
} else {
    echo "No results";
}
?>
```